# TableLayout within HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, view, tablelayout

I am using following code to create a `TableLayout` which is scrollable horizontally:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:minWidth="200dp"
           android:scrollbars="none">

       <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"            android:id="@+id/maintable2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"                  
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"                     
                android:stretchColumns="*"                      
                android:background ="#dddddd"           
                android:scrollbars="none"   >       
       </TableLayout>               
   </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I need the columns in the `TableLayout` to at least fill the screen (i.e. if there is only one column, the borders of that columns should stretch over the whole screen, if there are two columns, the borders of both columns should fill the screen etc.).

How can I do that?

Comment: Well `android:stretchColumns="*"` should do just that. What's the problem?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. I solved it by adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `HorizontalScrollView`.

Answer (score -1):

Showing three columns with equal size next to each other

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"                  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background ="#dddddd"
    />
<TableLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"                  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    />
<TableLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"                  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background ="#dddddd"
    />
```

Comment: Benjamin, your answer is seriously flawed. Not only it does not use HorizontalScrollView, but it also uses three separate TableLayouts each serving as column. That does not make sense. There should be one TableLayout with TableRow(s) containing views as contents of the columns.