# How can i change the render of a TableLayout depending on the dimension of its contents?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have an `ExpandableListView` which is populated with some data that i retrieve from a web service. Inside a few of the child of this ExpView there are row populated by `TableLayout`. The problem is that **i'd like to set `setStretchAllColumns()` to true when the width of the table is minor than screen's one; at the same time i'd like to put the table in a `ScroolView` if its width is greater than screen's one** (to let the user scrolls through all the data in the large table).
I have tried using ViewTreeObserver but with no success.

Can you help me with some code or a tutorial or just pointing me in the right direction plz?

PS:sorry for my poor english, be patient.

I post here the source of my `ExpandableListViewAdapter`, it's a mess but will help you understand what i'm trying to achieve. The important methods are `createTableOnUIThread` and `init`.

```
public class MyExpListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private final int TABLE_BORDER = 1;
    private final int TABLE_TEXT_PADDING = 10;

    private Context context = null;

    private List<String> keyList = null;

    private Map<String, List<LabelValueTable>> infoMap = null;

    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public MyExpListAdapter(Context context, Map<String, List<LabelValueTable>> infoMap) {
        this.context = context;
        this.infoMap = infoMap;
        this.keyList = new ArrayList<String>(infoMap.keySet());
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return this.infoMap.get(this.keyList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LabelValueTable listElement = (LabelValueTable) this.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        SubTableApparato table = listElement.getTable();

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.cmp_ac_scheda__expview_child, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.labelvalueContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmp_expview_child__labelvalue_container);

            holder.label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmp_expview_child__label);
            holder.value = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmp_expview_child__value);

            holder.tableHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmp_expview_child__tableheader);

            holder.tableScroll = (HorizontalScrollView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmp_expview_child__scrollview);

            holder.tableLayout = (TableLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmp_expview_child__tablelayout);
            holder.tableLayoutScrollable = (TableLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmp_expview_child__tablelayout_scrollable);

            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.scheda_asset_oggetto_apparato_layout);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Se table è diverso da null disegno la tabella
        if (table != null) {
            holder.tableLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            holder.tableLayoutScrollable.removeAllViewsInLayout();

            // Gruppo di controlli per il reset del layout
            holder.tableHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tableScroll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tableLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tableLayoutScrollable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.labelvalueContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            this.createTableOnUIThread(table, holder.tableHeader, holder.tableLayout, holder.tableLayoutScrollable);
        } else {
            // Altrimenti imposto i due valori label e value nelle rispettive
            // textview
            holder.tableHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tableScroll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tableLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tableLayoutScrollable.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.labelvalueContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.label.setText(((LabelValueTable) listElement).getLabelValue().getLabel());

            holder.value.setText(((LabelValueTable) listElement).getLabelValue().getValue());

        }
        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this.infoMap.get(this.keyList.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.keyList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.infoMap.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.cmp_ac_scheda__expview_group, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmp_expview_group__groupname);

            holder.tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.title_bar_bg_color);
            holder.tv.setTextColor(convertView.getResources().getColor(R.color.title_text_color));
            holder.tv.setBackgroundResource((R.drawable.scheda_asset__groupview_bg_style));

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.tv.setText((String) getGroup(groupPosition));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    private LinearLayout createFormattedCell(boolean isTabHeader, boolean isLast, String str) {
        // Layout che circonda le textView necessario per disegnare il bordo
        // delle celle
        LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(this.context);

        container.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        if (isLast) {
            container.setPadding(TABLE_BORDER, TABLE_BORDER, TABLE_BORDER, 0);
        } else {
            container.setPadding(TABLE_BORDER, TABLE_BORDER, 0, 0);
        }

        TextView textView = new TextView(this.context);

        textView.setPadding(TABLE_TEXT_PADDING, TABLE_TEXT_PADDING, TABLE_TEXT_PADDING, TABLE_TEXT_PADDING);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

        if (isTabHeader) {
            textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setBackgroundColor(this.context.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_grayish_orange));
        }
        textView.setText(str);
        container.addView(textView);

        return container;
    }

    private void createTableRows(List<List<String>> table, TableLayout tableLayout) {
        for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
            List<String> record = table.get(i);
            TableRow column = new TableRow(this.context);
            // If necessario per l'identificazione delle intestazioni delle
            // colonne
            if (i == 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < record.size(); j++) {
                    String cellValue = record.get(j);
                    // If necessario per l'inserimento del bordo destro
                    // sull'ultima cella
                    if (j == record.size() - 1) {
                        column.addView(this.createFormattedCell(true, true, cellValue));
                    } else {
                        column.addView(this.createFormattedCell(true, false, cellValue));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < record.size(); j++) {
                    String cellValue = record.get(j);

                    if (j == record.size() - 1) {
                        column.addView(this.createFormattedCell(false, true, cellValue));
                    } else {
                        column.addView(this.createFormattedCell(false, false, cellValue));
                    }
                }
            }
            tableLayout.addView(column);
        }
    }

    private void createTableOnUIThread(SubTableApparato tableEntity, TextView tableHeader, final TableLayout tableLayout, final TableLayout tableLayoutScrollable) {
        // Setto il titolo della table
        tableHeader.setText(tableEntity.getTableName());

        List<List<String>> table = tableEntity.getTable();

        // if (table.size() != 0 && table.get(0).size() <= 3) {
        // // Se la tabella è vuota setto le colonne per non superare la
        // // larghezza dello schermo
        // this.createTableRows(table, tableLayout);
        // tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        // // tableLayout.getWidth();
        // } else {
        // tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(false);
        // this.createTableRows(table, tableLayoutScrollable);
        // }
        final TableLayout provvisorio = new TableLayout(this.context);
        tableLayoutScrollable.removeAllViews();
        tableLayoutScrollable.addView(provvisorio);

        final TableLayout provvisorio2 = new TableLayout(this.context);
        tableLayout.removeAllViews();
        provvisorio2.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        tableLayout.addView(provvisorio2);

        this.createTableRows(table, provvisorio);
        this.createTableRows(table, provvisorio2);

        ViewTreeObserver observer = provvisorio.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                init(provvisorio, tableLayoutScrollable);
                provvisorio.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });

        ViewTreeObserver observer1 = provvisorio2.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer1.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                init(provvisorio2, tableLayout);
                provvisorio2.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });

        // if (provvisorioWidth <= width) {
        // provvisorio.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        // tableLayout.addView(provvisorio);
        // } else {
        // provvisorio.setStretchAllColumns(false);
        // tableLayoutScrollable.addView(provvisorio);
        // }

    }

    protected void init(TableLayout l, TableLayout tableLayout) {
        Display display = ((Activity) (this.context)).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int screenWidth = size.x;
        int b = l.getMeasuredWidthAndState();
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "Width schermo:" + screenWidth + " Widht view:" + b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (b <= screenWidth) {
            tableLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            tableLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        // Child view
        TextView label = null;
        TextView value = null;

        TextView tableHeader = null;

        LinearLayout labelvalueContainer = null;

        HorizontalScrollView tableScroll = null;

        TableLayout tableLayout = null;

        TableLayout tableLayoutScrollable = null;

        // Group view
        TextView tv = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> solved it by adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `HorizontalScrollView`

thx to Guspodes for this solution: [TableLayout within HorizontalScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036867/tablelayout-within-horizontalscrollview)